# vagrant linux box connection speed to AWS RDS mariadb database

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, amazon-rds

I and my team of developers have Vagrant machines running on our Windows 10 computers that have local file systems which contain our scripts to run a developer version of our web application.

We connect to an AWS RDS DB, but the connection is extremely slow to the database.

If we use our database IDE (dbforge) and run SQL queries, then they run fast.

Is there anything we can do to our vagrant boxes or setup that would speed this connection up?

Here are the contents of our Vagrantfile

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing. Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|   
# The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.   
# For acomplete reference, please see the online documentation at   
# https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for   
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.  
config.vm.box = "hcp"   config.vm.network "private_network", ip:
"10.23.45.30"   config.vm.synced_folder "etc/", "/etc/hcp"  
config.vm.synced_folder "html/", "/var/www/html"  
config.vm.synced_folder "html_data/", "/var/www/html/_data"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then  
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs   
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.   
  #config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port   
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,   
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.   
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port   
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host:8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port   
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access   
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access   
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine   
  # using a specific IP.   
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.   
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on   
  # your network.   
  # config.vm.network "public_network"
 

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is 
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is   
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third   
  # argument is a set of non-required options.   
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various   
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:   
  #   
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|   
  #   
  # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine   
  #  vb.gui = true   
  #   
  #   
  # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:  
#   vb.memory = "1024"   
# end   
#   
# View the documentation for the provider you are using for more   
# information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as   
  # Ansible, Chef, Docker, Puppet and Salt are also available. Please see the   
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.   
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline:<<-SHELL   
  #   apt-get update   
  #   apt-get install -y apache2   
  #
SHELL end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I made a edit to your snippet as it was almost unreadable, formatting and word-wrapping confusing what is code and what are still comments. After the edit is approved, could you check if I didn't mess up something in the meantime?

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry for the mishap.  I will do a better next time.

Comment: Still looking for help, if anyone could help resolve this, I would truly appreciate it